# XML IDREF another XML document?

Tags: xml, idref

Is there an easy way to use the IDREF attribute to reference an element in a different XML document? If not, any suggestions on how to do it differently? What I'm trying to do is make a digital character sheet for a table-top RPG, and I want the XML document that contains all of the character-specific information to reference a master list of all of the merits. Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm fairly new to using XML, or even any programming language, and have just discovered how much XML can make things easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An IDREF is a type defined to reference other element IDs within the same document. Therefore, you will first need to use "XInclude" to reference your external file and then use IDREFs as this was one single file. A similar question you might find useful is [available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065026/xml-referencing-other-xml-files)